# ngOptions creating strange results for value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following select element.

```
<select ng-model="current_addon_ids" 
    ng-options="addon.id as addon.name for addon in addons"></select>
```

The $scope variables that are relevant have the following values at the beginning.

```
$scope.addons = [{id: 701, name: "Item1"},{id: 702, name: "Item2"}];
$scope.current_addon_ids = [];
```

I would expect a select element witht the following options:

```
<option value="701">Item1</option>
<option value="702">Item2</option>
```

However, what I get is:

```
<option value="number:701">Item1</option>
<option value="number:702">Item2</option>
```

Why is it adding the "number:" to the id?  How do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a change in how the ngOptions directive is handled. This change is briefly explained in the [migration notes for AngularJS 1.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngoptions). A more detailed description of the changes can be found in the [commit message](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef):

When using ngOptions: the directive applies a surrogate key as the value of the  element. This commit changes the actual string used as the surrogate key. We now store a string that is computed by calling hashKey on the item in the options collection; previously it was the index or key of the item in the collection.

```
<select ng-model="current_addon_ids" 
    ng-options="addon.id as addon.label for addon in addons track by addon.id"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This answers the question perfectly and everything is working now.

Answer (score 2):

This is occurring due to angular internally adding the type identifier to avoid possible duplication during iteration.  You can correct for this by using the `track by` option, if you know for certain that you will not have duplicates.

For example:

```
<select ng-model="current_addon_ids" 
ng-options="addon.id as addon.name for addon in addons track by addon.id"></select>
```

Output:

```
<option label="Item1" value="701">Item1</option>
<option label="Item2" value="702">Item2</option>
```

Comment: Dude, I totally missed this answer. It is pretty much identical to the one I chose as the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `track by item.id` , if your collection items have an id property, you would track by item.id.

refer : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<select ng-model="current_addon_ids" 
    ng-options="addon.name for addon in addons track by addon.id"></select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z2cnjn4c/

Comment: This was useful so I voted it up.  I selected the answer below as the actual answer because it gave me a reason for why it was happening and I actually had to use "addon.id as addon.name for addon in addons track by addon.id" to make it work.  Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question.  I appreciate it.